# Running Multiple spiders in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

1. In scrapy for example if i had two URL's that contains different HTML. Now i want to write two individual spiders each for one and want to run both the spiders at once. In scrapy is it possible to run multiple spiders at once.
2. In scrapy after writing multiple spiders, how can we schedule them to run for every 6 hours(May be like cron jobs)

I had no idea of above , can u suggest me how to perform the above things with an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to just run two scrapy scripts at once from the OS level. They should both be able to save to the same database. Create a shell script to call both scrapy scripts to do them at the same time:

```
scrapy runspider foo &
scrapy runspider bar
```

Be sure to make this script executable with `chmod +x script_name`

To schedule a cronjob every 6 hours, type `crontab -e` into your terminal, and edit the file as follows:

```
* */6 * * * path/to/shell/script_name >> path/to/file.log
```

The first * is minutes, then hours, etc., and an asterik is a wildcard. So this says run the script at any time where the hours is divisible by 6, or every six hours.

Comment: Thanks very much for u r reply, don't mind i am asking this, can u give an example code for this so that it will be more help full nd i can make it further

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `CrawlerProcess`

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from myproject.spiders import spider1, spider2

1Spider = spider1.1Spider()
2Spider = spider2.2Spider()
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(1Spider)
process.crawl(2Spider)
process.start()
```

If you want to see the full log of the crawl, set `LOG_FILE` in your `settings.py`.

```
LOG_FILE = "logs/mylog.log"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the code that allow you to run multiple spiders in scrapy. Save this code at the same directory with scrapy.cfg (My scrapy version is 1.3.3 and it works) :

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name,query="dvh") #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
```

and then you can schedule this python program to run with cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

You should use scrapyd to handle multiple crawler
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html