# How to run several versions of one single spider at one time with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

My problematic is the following:

To win time, I would like to run several versions of **one single** spider.
The process (parsing definitions) is the same, the items are the same, and the collection in database is the same. What is changing is the start_url variable.
It looks like this:

```
"https://www.website.com/details/{0}-{1}-{2}/{3}/meeting".format(year,month,day,type_of_meeting)
```

Considering the date is the same, for instance 2018-10-24, I would like to launch two versions in the same time:

- version 1 `type_of_meeting = pmu`
- version 2 with `type_of_meeting = pmh`

This is the first part of my problematic. And here I wonder if I must create two different classes in **one single** spider, like `class SpiderPmu(scrapy.Spider):` and `class SpiderPmh(scrapy.Spider):` in `spider.py`. But if it is the best way you think I must do, I don't know how to implement it considering settings.py, pipelines.py. I already read about `CrawlerProcess` from `scrapy.crawler` module but I don't understand well how to implement it in my project. [stack subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943745/running-multiple-spiders-in-scrapy), [scrapy doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process). I am not sure the part 
`process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start()` must be in the spider.py file. Above all, I am not sure it answers to my problematic.

The second part, is how to launch several versions considering different date intervals.

I already created some range of intervals in my spider class like:

- `year  = range(2005,2019)`
- `month = range(1,13)`
- `day   = range(1,32)`

and put it in a loop. That works well.

But to win time, I would like to launch several spiders, with different intervals of years.

- 1st version with `year = range(2005,2007)`
- 2nd version with `year = range(2007,2009)`
- and so on, until `year = range(2017,2019)`

Seven versions in the same time means seven times faster.

I could create 7 different projects for each range of years, but I think this is not the smartest way... and I am not sure if it will, or not, create a conflict to use the same collection database for 7 different projects running in the same time.

I expect to do something like opening 7 commands:

1. `scrapy crawl spiderpmu` for the version `type_of_race = pmu`
2. `"Enter a range of year":` with `raw_input = 2010, 2012` ==> `range(2010,2012)`
3. Spider is crawling

in parallel, if this is compulsory, to do:

1. `scrapy crawl spiderpmh` for the version `type_of_race = pmh`
2. `"Enter a range of year":` with `raw_input = 2010, 2012` ==> `range(2010,2012)`
3. Spider is crawling

Possibly using **one single** spider, or **one single** project if needed.

How can I do?

PS: I already made arrangements with prolipo as proxy, Tor network to change IP, and `USER_AGENT` always changing. So, I avoid to be banned by crawling with multiple spiders in the same time. And my spider is "polite" with `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True`. I want to keep it polite, but faster.

Scrapy version: 1.5.0, Python version: 2.7.9, Mongodb version: 3.6.4, Pymongo version: 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I find a solution inspired of the `scrapy crawl -a variable=value`

The spider concerned, in "spiders" folder was transformed:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "arg"
allowed_domains = ['www.website.com']

    def __init__ (self, lo_lim=None, up_lim=None , type_of_race = None) : #lo_lim = 2017 , up_lim = 2019, type_of_race = pmu
        year  = range(int(lo_lim), int(up_lim)) # lower limit, upper limit, must be convert to integer type, instead this is string type
        month = range(1,13) #12 months
        day   = range(1,32) #31 days
        url   = []
        for y in year:
            for m in month:
                for d in day:
                    url.append("https://www.website.com/details/{}-{}-{}/{}/meeting".format(y,m,d,type_of_race))

        self.start_urls = url #where url = ["https://www.website.com/details/2017-1-1/pmu/meeting",
                                        #"https://www.website.com/details/2017-1-2/pmu/meeting",
                                        #...
                                        #"https://www.website.com/details/2017-12-31/pmu/meeting"
                                        #"https://www.website.com/details/2018-1-1/pmu/meeting",
                                        #"https://www.website.com/details/2018-1-2/pmu/meeting",
                                        #...
                                        #"https://www.website.com/details/2018-12-31/pmu/meeting"]

    def parse(self, response):
        ...`
```

Then, it answers to my problematic: to keep **one single** spider, and to run several versions of it by serveral commands **at one time** without trouble.

Without a `def __init__` it didn't work for me. I tried a lot of ways, that is this perfectible code that works for me.

Scrapy version: 1.5.0, Python version: 2.7.9, Mongodb version: 3.6.4, Pymongo version: 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy supports spider arguments. Weirdly enough there's no straightforward documentation, but I'll try to fill in:

When you run a `crawl` command you may provide `-a NAME=VALUE` arguments and these will be set as your spider class instance variables. For example:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'arg'
    # we will set below when running the crawler
    foo = None 
    bar = None

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f'http://example.com/{self.foo}/{self.bar}'
        yield Request(url)
```

And if we run it:

```
scrapy crawl arg -a foo=1 -a bar=2
# will crawl example.com/1/2
```

Comment: I haven't f-string like f "string". So I adapted `class MySpider(Spider):

name = 'arg'
global day
day = None

def start_requests(self):
url = "https://www.website.com/details/2018-10-{day}/pmu/meeting".format(**globals())
yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
` 
When I run `scrapy crawl arg -a day = 19` or even `day = "19"`, the argument day keep the value None.
The command shows : `<GET https://www.website.com/details/2018-10-None/pmu/meeting>(failed 1 times): 404 Not Found`

Comment: and I tried with `self.day`, it kept `https://www.website.com/details/2018-10-{self.day}/pmu/meeting`and it says `KeyError: 'self' `. That is why I adapted too with `(**globals())`

Comment: After some researchs that you inspired me with your `scrapy crawl arg -a foo=1 -a bar=2` example.  I found a way that works. Inspired by this [website's example](http://neuralfoundry.com/pass-user-defined-argument-scrapy-spider/), I did 
`class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "arg"
 allowed_domains = ['www.website.com']
 
def __init__ (self, day=None, *args, **kwargs) :
 super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 self.start_urls = ["https://www.website.com/details/2018-10-{0}/pmu/meeting".format(day)]
 
def parse(self, response):
 ...
`
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The constructor in your example is completely unnecessary other than for visual explicitness.