# How to run faster several version of one single spider at one time with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I found a solution to run several version of one single spider in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977185/how-to-run-several-versions-of-one-single-spider-at-one-time-with-scrapy).

So I run this several versions at one time with several different windows commands:

```
scrapy crawl spider -a lo_lim=2005 -a up_lim=2007 ...
scrapy crawl spider -a lo_lim=2007 -a up_lim=2009  ...
scrapy crawl spider -a lo_lim=2009 -a up_lim=2011  ...
```

I used 7 versions in once.

My issue is when I run many spiders like this, I see with my own eyes the process became so slow. And this is visible too in the log with `'finish_time'` and `'start_time'`. It takes about 1 hour for each command if I use two versions at one time. It takes more than seven hours, very more, for each command if I use seven versions at one time.

In the `settings.py` I wrote

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 128
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25 
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=64 
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
```

I am sure it is not enough because I see the results, but am I wrong to think these configurations are the ways to increase the velocity? And how could I do to make my crawling to be faster?

PS: I use Tor with Vidalia and Polipo as proxy. So I know my connexion can't be very fast, that is the cons of the anonymity. But the real issue is when I run several at one time. And my CPU is far away of its max capacity.

Scrapy version: 1.5.0, Python version: 2.7.9

Comment: If you are launching those jobs in parallel and find that all of them are (much) slower than when being launching individually, it's highly suspected that the bottleneck is not Scrapy (the CPU usage, the proxy throughput, your internet connection, the target site's capacity, etc.). Scrapy's settings are per-job.

Comment: Do you think the proxy matter? To change Polipo proxy for another one can change something about it?